# What part of speech is "spruce" in "The Templar spruce"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

While reading Swift's "A Description of a City Shower" (1710) I met the following two lines:

> The Templar spruce, while every spout’s abroach,
>
> Stays till ’tis fair, yet seems to call a coach.

It is fairly clear from the context that these lines describe a dapper law student(or a lawyer?) caught in a sudden shower.

What is less clear, however, is the part of speech the word "spruce" belongs to here.
From the word order it seems to be a noun, yet no dictionary I have checked, not even OED, lists that word as such in the sense of someone neatly dressed.

So what part of speech is it? Is it a postpositive adjective? (If so, was it used for the sake of poetic fluidity, or was it a common grammatical feature back then?) Was the word turned into a noun by the potent magic of poetry?

Comment: It's an adjective, probably placed after the noun for reasons of poetic style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templar is a noun; spruce would be an adjective describing it (it has been around since the sixteenth century, so would be apt for a Swiftian text)

Definition of spruce:  neat or smart in appearance :  trim.

Sometimes we put an adjective after the noun for effect, or rhyming purposes. Here's one I made earlier:
"The Templar fat, did eat my cat..."

Comment: *Almost* a good answer. You really need to cite and link your references; e.g., one or more dictionary citations, a Google Ngram, etc.

Comment: I don't have any specific refs per se for this particular query. I'm a polyglot native English speaker, former TEFL trainer and currently a full-time ES-EN translator. The entirety of my response is based on my own knowledge, acquired over decades.